# Find the rank of matrix, where $a \in \mathbb R$

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

> Let $a \; \in \; \mathbb{R}$. Find the rank of the matrix
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix}
> -a&1&2&3&1\\
> 1&-a&3&2&1\\
> 2&3&-a&1&1\\
> 3&2&1&-a&1
> \end{pmatrix}$$

This is one of my exercises. I tried to use some elementary operations to transform this matrix to RRE form, but it seems like it is really complicated to complete. Help me, please. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe look at the submatrix found by removing the $5$th column. The resultant submatrix will be square, you can take the determinant and see for which values $a$ the determinant is nonzero. I hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for your help. that a good way but our problem is find rank of the matrix, not find all values "a" in R such that rank of the matrix is 4.  I think that means in some cases of value "a" we will have rank of the matrix is 1,2,3 . Or if not, we have to proof.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Since row rank equals column rank, the rank of the matrix is at most $4$. To prove that the rank is $4$, it suffices to compute the determinant of two $4\times 4$ minors and check that they don't have common factor as polynomials in ${\mathbb R}[a]$. For example, the matrix consisting of the first four column vectors has determinant $a(a+4)(a+2)(a-6)$. Then either you can compute one more determinant and check for common factor, or work on the four cases $a=0,-4,-2,6$ to see that the resulting matrix indeed has rank $4$. Note that if $a$ is none of the above values, the rank will be $4$.

Comment: "if a is none of the above values, the rank will be $4$" here is a counterexample $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&2&3&4\\ 1&1&3&2&1\\ 2&2&1&1&1\\ 3&3&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$ has rank $3$

Comment: @emonHR No, your $3\times 2$ and $4\times 2$ entries are misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are getting stuck. Apply Gaussian elimination to convert to reduced echelon form and constraints on $a$ will be obvious from there.